# Multitasks in discord py bot

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py, multitasking

I'm trying to multitask with discord py, but I have a problem

Code:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def taskLoop(ctx, something):

    await ctx.send(something)

@client.command()
async def startX(ctx, something):
    
    taskLoop.start(ctx, something)

@client.command()
async def endX(ctx):
    
    taskLoop.cancel()
    taskLoop.stop()
```

In discord I start the command like: `-startX zzzzzzzzzz`

So it works, every 10 seconds the bot sends "zzzzzzzzzz"

When I try to create a new task (while the previous one is still running), for example: `-startX yyyyyyyy`

I get the error:

`Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: Task is already launched and is not completed.`

Obviously I understand it's because the other task is still working, but I looked in the documentation and couldn't find a way to create multiple tasks.

Are there any solutions for this? Thread maybe?

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce this. I think the issue is most likely calling both loop.cancel and loop.stop. just use loop.stop

Comment: The problem is not that, it's to create new tasks, the stop() and cancel() is to stop.

Comment: why both? why not just one

Comment: If I only use stop(), the bot always sends 1 more message after the stop command, because it had already created a thread to send this message, cancel() is used to cancel the one that had not been sent yet.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.cancel

Comment: then just use cancel and don't use stop

Comment: I've tested it now and it only works with cancel(), I thought it would only interrupt once and keep running, but it interrupts everything too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really start the same task more than once. You can create a "task generator" which will generate and start the tasks

```py
started_tasks = []

async def task_loop(ctx, something):  # the function that will "loop"
    await ctx.send(something)


def task_generator(ctx, something):
    t = tasks.loop(seconds=10)(task_loop)
    started_tasks.append(t)
    t.start(ctx, something)


@bot.command()
async def start(ctx, something):
    task_generator(ctx, something)


@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    for t in started_tasks:
        t.cancel()
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know this form of arguments in 2 different parentheses `t = tasks.loop(seconds=10)(task_loop)`, I'll look into it more, thanks.

Comment: It’s a decorator, decorators return a function, which is why the second parenthesis

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't even know then. I will learn about, thanks xD.